# Calling a php function from another php page on onload event of page?

Tags: php, onload-event

I have defined some functions in class described in php page named as phpFunctions for example.
Now i want to call any function of phpFunctions page on onload event of another page named as phpCalling for example.

One way is onload attribute of body tag.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What you want you do is called ajax, the `onload` attribute or equivalent methods by themselves can only be used to call client, ie javascript, functions.

Comment: PHP is run ON SERVER before it is viewed on screen so you cannot do this.

However you may use javascript to load in the php file anywhere on the page to call for a php file. (which holds the function call  `functionname(Parameters);` )
It could also be achieved with an image.

Comment: This may work as well `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.php" />`